# Netty: How to limit websocket channel messages per second?

Tags: java, websocket, netty

I need to limit messages received on websocket channel per second for netty server.
Could'n find any ideas how to do that.

Any ideas would be appreciated

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add simple `ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter` handler to your pipeline and add the simple counter to `channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg)` method. I would recommend you to use some of CodaHale Metrics Class for that purpose.

Pseudo code:

```
private final QuotaLimitChecker limitChecker;

public MessageDecoder() {
    this.limitChecker = new QuotaLimitChecker();
}


@Override 
public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) {
    if (limitChecker.quotaReached(100)) { //assume limit is 100 req per sec
        return;
    }
}
```

Where `QuotaLimitChecker` is a class that increments counter and checks if the limit is reached.

```
public class QuotaLimitChecker {

    private final static Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(QuotaLimitChecker.class);

    private final int userQuotaLimit;
    //here is specific implementation of Meter for your needs
    private final InstanceLoadMeter quotaMeter;

    public QuotaLimitChecker(int userQuotaLimit) {
        this.userQuotaLimit = userQuotaLimit;
        this.quotaMeter = new InstanceLoadMeter();
    }

    public boolean quotaReached() {
        if (quotaMeter.getOneMinuteRate() > userQuotaLimit) {
            log.debug("User has exceeded message quota limit.");
            return true;
        }
        quotaMeter.mark();
        return false;
    }

}
```

[Here is](https://github.com/blynkkk/blynk-server/blob/d0df6a376e56d04de7170b87f3a956e6ea100bf4/server/core/src/main/java/cc/blynk/server/handlers/QuotaLimitChecker.java#L37) my implementation of `QuotaLimitChecker` that uses the simplified version [Meter](http://metrics.dropwizard.io/3.1.0/apidocs/com/codahale/metrics/Meter.html) class of CodaHale Metrics library.

Comment: Thank you this is what I need :)